# Something broke mid-update, is there any way to recover?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I seem to have gotten myself in a huge mess, I'm hoping somebody here can help me sort it out.
When I run `sudo apt upgrade` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 sabnzbdplus : Depends: python3-sabyenc but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` which gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  activity-log-manager advancecomp apport-symptoms apt-config-icons-hidpi apt-config-icons-large apt-config-icons-large-hidpi autopilot-qt4 autopilot-qt5 compton dc fbset gaviotatb gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-bamf-3 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0
  gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-mutter-2 gir1.2-nm-1.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gjs
  gnome-shell-common gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal-data gnome-user-guide gtk3-nocsd hud ippusbxd libasound2-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcolumbus1-common libcolumbus1v5 libcompizconfig0 libconfig9 libdbus-1-dev libfdk-aac-dev libfdk-aac1 libflatpak0 libfontconfig1-dev libframe6 libfreetype6-dev
  libfribidi-dev libgaviotatb1 libgeis1 libgeonames-common libgeonames0 libgjs0g libglewmx1.13 libgrail6 libgsettings-qt1 libgtk3-nocsd0 libio-multiplex-perl libmetacity1 libmirclient-dev libmircommon-dev libmircookie-dev libmircookie2 libmircore-dev libmozjs-52-0 libmp3lame-dev libnet-cidr-perl libnet-server-perl
  libnet-snmp-perl libnetplan0 libnm-gtk0 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libopus-dev libpixman-1-dev libpng-dev libpng-tools libprotobuf-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib libqt5quickparticles5 libqt5quicktest5 libsane-hpaio libset-scalar-perl libsignon-glib1 libsndio-dev
  libtimezonemap-data libtimezonemap1 libudev-dev libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libunity-gtk2-parser0 libunity-misc4 libva-dev libva-glx2 libvdpau-dev libvpx-dev libx264-dev libx265-dev libxatracker2 libxcb-ewmh2 libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xrm0 libxcb-xtest0 libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxft-dev
  libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxpathselect1.4v5 libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev libxss-dev libxv-dev libzeitgeist-1.0-1 mate-applet-appmenu metacity-common mscompress munin-common munin-node munin-plugins-core munin-plugins-extra nux-tools ogmrip-dirac ogmrip-doc ogmrip-oggz ogmrip-plugins ogmtools
  optipng plasma-discover-common python-apt python-contextlib2 python-debian python-decorator python-defer python-extras python-fixtures python-junitxml python-linecache2 python-mimeparse python-qt4-dbus python-subunit python-testscenarios python-testtools python-traceback2 python-unittest2 python3.7-minimal
  qtdeclarative5-dev rofi session-shortcuts unity-asset-pool unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-video unity-schemas unity-scope-video-remote vala-panel-appmenu-common vala-panel-appmenu-registrar vorbis-tools x11-apps x11-session-utils x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xinit xinput xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware xwayland yasm
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-sabyenc
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libgksu2-0
The following NEW packages will be installed
  python3-sabyenc
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 to remove and 42 not to upgrade.
52 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/55.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 398 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 728280 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-9ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgksu2-0.postrm: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgksu2-0.postrm: update-gconf-defaults: not found
dpkg: error processing package libgksu2-0 (--remove):
 installed libgksu2-0 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgksu2-0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and now I'm stuck, I've been Googling for hours trying various things to recover my system, but I can't seem to make any headway. Any suggestions to fix this mess?

Comment: *"trying various things to recover my system"* - it's pretty important that we know what those things are. If something you tried didn't fix the problem, it's possible that you added to the problem, which could add another layer of complexity to the problem. Can you edit your question with these details?

Comment: Did you do something to your system's python installation?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, but was trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, so I may be stuck in some no-mans-land between the two. I don't recall screwing with python, but it does seem very broken as nothing that needs it runs now as far as I can see. When I type python --version or python -V it gives me: Python 3.8.8

Comment: You weren't trying to *release-upgrade* a Ubuntu system using Debian methods; as Ubuntu relies more heavily on python3 than Debian does thus it's different `python3` protections steps, and python3 issues can be expected when Debian *release-upgrade* steps are performed.

Comment: I was following this: https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today as it's on ubuntu.com I assumed it was the correct way to do it.

Comment: No you'll be doing it correctly following instructions from an official Ubuntu blog..   *I just wonder where [`libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-9ubuntu2)`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/libgksu2-0/2.0.13~pre1-9ubuntu2) came from as I don't see it, thus wonder about your sources... I'm missing something sorry so can't currently offer more... `gksu` was deprecated some time ago so you've changed your system to require it??

Comment: So does that mean I'm screwed?

Comment: No; it's a complication that occurred so long ago I no longer remember specific details or the *fix* that then existed (https://launchpad.net/bugs/1740618 - ie. 2017-2018 & pre *bionic* release).  You likely used *tricks* (or *hacks*) in getting to *bionic* & getting it installed back on 18.04; those *hacks* are now *biting* you badly, and what you did that included the non-18.04 packages (*details in my first now deleted common on unsupported package*) is likely key, but you'll not likely remember either.  Maybe someone else did what you did & will have clues.

Comment: The output seems to clearly show that the fatal problem occurs during removal of package `libgksu2-0`. That particular package was removed from Ubuntu after 16.04, suggesting that your migration from 16.04 to 18.04 was incomplete or haywired or otherwise broken/non-standard. Remove the package using one of dpkg's `--force` options. Or consider a fresh install to rid yourself of ALL such forgotten hacks.

Comment: OK, I tried 'sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgksu2-0' and this was the output:
'(Reading database ... 728280 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-9ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgksu2-0.postrm: 15: /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgksu2-0.postrm: update-gconf-defaults: not found
dpkg: error processing package libgksu2-0 (--purge):
 installed libgksu2-0 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgksu2-0'

Comment: Any other suggestions on what I can try? My system is badly broken and I have no idea how to fix it.